# Как динамическому блоку изменить цвет?

Tags: javascript, jquery

У меня не изменяет цвет блока

```
$(".w1").append("<div id='#s"+i+"'>"  +  m[i].mg + "</div>");
$(".btn").click(function(){
  $(".s1").css(background,red);
})
```

Comment: Так у этого блока нет класса. Есть только идентификатор.

Answer (score 3):

Вы напутали с селекторами:

```js
$(".w1").append("<div id='s1'>123</div>");
$(".btn").click(function() {
  $("#s1").css('background', 'red');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="w1">
  <button class="btn">click</button>
</div>
```

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0jkc0dh4/)

Answer (score 1):

Создаёте новый элемент и потом к нему обращаетесь через переменную.

```js
var m = [{mg: 'Мой текст'}],
    i = 0;

var $new_element = $("<div id='#s" + i + "'>" + m[i].mg + "</div>");

$(".w1").append($new_element);

$(".btn").click(function() {
  $new_element.css('background', 'red');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="w1">
  <button class="btn">Изменить цвет</button>
</div>
```